# Referencing cells in the same row

Tags: python, openpyxl

**I'm using Openpyxl. I'm open to answers using other methods/modules as well.**

So to reference a cell value, you can do:

```
ws = wb.get_active_sheet()
for cellobject in sheet.columns[1]:
    print(cellobject.value)


1001
1002
1003
1004
```

But what If I wanted to reference a cell in the same row, for example column C (kind of like a vlookup formula)?

```
| A          |  B          | 
|:-----------|------------:|
| 1001       |  Cow        |       
| 1002       |  Cat        |     
| 1003       |  Dog        |         
| 1004       |  Mouse      |
```

So the end result may look something like:

```
(1001, Cow)
(1002, Cat)
```

or:

```
1001
Cow
1002
Cat
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try going over `ws.rows` , this will give you each row (complete with all the columns) one by one, example -

```
for row in ws.rows:
    print((row[0].value, row[1].value)) #for first and second column.
```

or you can iterate over the row as well, to get each cell in the row. Example -

```
for row in ws.rows:
    for cell in row:
        print(cell.value) #this will print cell by cell , in a new line.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass first and second columns to zip function.

```
for cellobject1, cellobject2 in zip(sheet.columns[1], sheet.columns[1]):
    print((cellobject1.value, cellobject2.value))
```

Answer (score 1):

Correction of 2. Answer:
*Just pass first and second columns to zip() function.*

```
for cell01, cell02 in zip(sheet.columns[0], sheet.columns[1]):
    print(cell01.value, cell02.value)
```

yielding "(1001, Cow)" etc.